# Magento 2 core files missing on cloud

Tags: magento2, javascript

Hi i have encountered a very strange error today in my console log where my js files are missing and this is the error which am getting in the console

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://domain.com/static/version1595961576/frontend/Test/Test2/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/resource/jarallax/jarallax.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

any fix for this please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from CLI and then check.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```